# Is it safe to leave an AWS IAM ARN value in a public Git repository?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I've created a CloudFormation template and would like to store it on my Public GitHub account.

I've created an IAM role that is associated with environments at creation. To achieve this I've included the ARN value of the Role in the environment configuration:

```
"WebServerEnvironment" : {
"Type" : "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment",
"Properties" : {
"OptionSettings":[
{
 "Namespace" : "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration",
 "OptionName" : "IamInstanceProfile",
 "Value" : "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:instance-profile/myCloudFormationNameHere"
}]
```

My question is, could this ARN value be used to compromise my app? Or due to the account specific nature of IAM access is this information *safe* in the public domain?

Answer (score 3):

If I'm not mistaken an ARN is not account specific but global. But on its own it's not super critical, since it is only a unique, but not too nice name for a resource.

Nevertheless, does this really need to go into source control? Couldn't this be solved with instance metadata / user data? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html

Comment: I'm really trying as much as possible to not put anything account specific into the configuration, but I'm limited by:  

* The permission levels on my account (I'm trying to get as far as possible without bothering my seniors)  

* What's possible in the environment configuration variables for [Elastic Beanstalk environments](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html)  

It's looking like I'll need to ensure that the IAM group to which I belong can list and apply IAM role settings.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend putting the IAM roles exposed to the public. It depends on what permissions the roles have. Let's say if myCloudFormationNameHere has permission to write, then anyone can use this and execute an action [if triggered on push or pull resquest]

1. Assign account number 1234567890 to a GitHub variable